# read.table() reading all data as a single row

Tags: r

I am trying to read a text file that consists of 9 columns and 208 rows.

To read it I use:

```
file=read.table("C:\\Users\\foo.txt",sep="")
> str(file)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  21 variables:  ### this not right
> class(file)
[1] "data.frame"
```

It seems that it misses everything. lastly I got this warning:

```
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\foo.txt'
```

Comment: This might be difficult to diagnose without access to the actual file. But these sorts of issues almost always boil down to something "odd" happening in your file that you are unaware of.

Comment: Maybe adjust the `comment.char` argument then...? But we're still just guessing, and there might still be more problems that we don't know of.

Comment: There seem to be no line breaks in your file ... However, there seems to be a systematic structure. So, maybe you could preprocess with a fast command line text editor (such as sed or awk) to add line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file quite small, we can read it with `readLines()` and then process it with a regular expression, by adding the appropriate line-breaks to get it ready for `read.table()`.  Also note that I have used `comment.char = ""` in the `read.table()` call.  This is so that we can successfully read those rows where a value might contain a `#`.

```
rl <- readLines("Downloads/coord.txt")
df <- read.table(
    text = gsub("(?<=\\S) (?=SCAN)", "\n", rl, perl = TRUE), 
    comment.char = ""
)
dim(df)
# [1] 208   9
```

Data not shown by request of OP.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have any end of line characters.  Given the structured nature, you could try

```
library(magrittr)
DF <- readLines(filename) %>%
  gsub("[)] XXXX", ") \nXXXX", .) %>%
  textConnection() %>%
  read.table(sep = "")
```

Where "XXXX" is the first four characters of the line.